# Text justified instead of centered?

Tags: tables

I am using this code to insert text below the label in the following table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!] 
\centering 
\caption{}
\label{Table1}{\textbf{Descriptive Statistics for the Industry. 2007 - 2017}} \\
 write here option 2 \\
 \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    ....
 \end{tabular}  
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

However as you can observe here, the text in (write here option 2) is centered and I want it justified.

[image]

Note: If I remove the centering and put it below, then the label is not centered and I want it centered.

Thank you!

Comment: it in only centred because you added `\centering`

Comment: note it is a bad idea to use a number such as `\label{Table1}` in the label, the point of labelling is that the cross references still work even if you insert a table and the automatic number changes and while latex will work with `\ref{Table1}` producing a reference to table 2 it is very confusing for a human reading the source

Comment: @chora Didn't you mean to say that you want that text to be no wider than the width of the table? I thought that was the crux of your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the text following the manually set caption is under the scope of `\centering`.

You can get more uniformity in the typesetting if you define a suitable command and use `caption` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,xparse}

\usepackage{lipsum} %% for mock text

\captionsetup[table]{
  font=bf,
  justification=centering,
  labelsep=newline,
  skip=0pt,
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bigcaption}{O{#2}mm}{%
  \caption[#1]{#2}
  \parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{#3}\par
  \medskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering 

\bigcaption{Descriptive Statistics for the Industry. 2007 - 2017}{%
  \lipsum[3]}\label{tab:desc-industry2007-2017}

\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
A & B & C & D & E \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}  

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Of course, instead of `\lipsum[3]` you will type

```
\bigcaption{Descriptive Statistics for the Industry. 2007 - 2017}{%
  This table shows...
  ...
  account for the analysis.}\label{tab:desc-industry2007-2017}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can have this solution, based on `makecell` and `threeparttablex` (requires to use a  `longtable`environment, hence two compilations). Also `siunitx` for the alignment of numbers in each column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{longtable, threeparttablex, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}%
\captionsetup{font = bf, labelsep=newline}
\setTableNoteFont{\small}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits =3}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]
  \item[]\lipsum[11]
\end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{l *{2}{S[table-format = -1.1]<{\,\%} } S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=4.0]}
    \caption{Descriptive Statistics for the Industry. 2007--2017}\label{Table1}\\[-2ex]
    \insertTableNotes\\
    \addlinespace[1.5ex]
    \toprule
    \endhead
            Year & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Avg. Monthly \\ Return}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Avg. Monthly \\ Std Dev. }} & {\thead{\# of Unique \\ Securities with \\ One Month Return}} & {\thead{Total \#\\of Observations}} \\
            \midrule
            2007 & -1.7 & 8.9 & 1043 & 11722 \\
            2008 & -3.5 & 17.0 & 986 & 11316 \\
            2009 & 1.1 & 22.4 & 907 & 10985 \\
            2010 & 1.6 & 15.8 & 840 & 9750 \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi! thank you so much. I am trying to do the same for a table with 11 columns, but it does not fit the page. I am trying to use the reshape command but I am getting error all the time. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can manually center the content of label with an environment, then adjust the vertical space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!] 
\caption{}
\label{Table1}{
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{Descriptive Statistics for the Industry. 2007 - 2017}
    \end{center}
}
%\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}%%%UNCOMMENT and adjust number if you want less space between lines
\lipsum[1] 
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
   ....
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}

 \end{document}
```